# KeyError at /api/rooms/create-grade/ 'grade'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I don't understand this error one bit, I'm trying to do a basic create method but I get a **KeyError** what am i doing wrong

**This is serializer.py code**

```
class GradeCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
grade = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=GRADES, source="get_grade_display")

class Meta:
    model = Grade
    fields = ["grade"]
    # ordering = ['-created_date']


def create(self, validated_data):
    user = None
    request = self.context.get("request")
    if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
        user = request.user

    try:
        perms = Perm.objects.get(user=user)
    except:
        perms = None

    if user.role in ['OWNER', 'PARTNER']:
        school = user.owns.first()
    elif perms is not None:
        if user.role == 'STAFF' and perms.can_crt_grade_class:
            school = user.works

    instance = Grade.objects.create(
        grade=validated_data['grade'],
        school=school,
    )
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

what am I doing wrong??

I have added the error traceback as requested
**error traceback**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Projects\SchoolProject\main\Abugida\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "F:\Projects\SchoolProject\main\Abugida\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\Projects\SchoolProject\main\Abugida\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Projects\SchoolProject\main\Abugida\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Projects\SchoolProject\main\Abugida\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "F:\Projects\SchoolProject\main\Abugida\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "F:\Projects\SchoolProject\main\Abugida\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "F:\Projects\SchoolProject\main\Abugida\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Projects\SchoolProject\main\Abugida\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 190, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Projects\SchoolProject\main\Abugida\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "F:\Projects\SchoolProject\main\Abugida\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 24, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "F:\Projects\SchoolProject\main\Abugida\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "F:\Projects\SchoolProject\main\Classes\serializers.py", line 45, in create
    grade=validated_data['grade'],
KeyError: 'grade'
```

it says that `grade=validated_data['grade'],` this the problem but i don't get it.

[image]

Comment: add error trace back

Comment: please post your request dto when you are calling api as well

Comment: i'm using the browsable api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my issue, it was because of `grade = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=GRADES, source="get_grade_display")` this means when using a ChoiceField to define your field you don't need to pass the `source=""` as the field uses the choice to determine it

So changing

```
 grade = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=GRADES, source="get_grade_display")
```

to

```
 grade = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=GRADES)
```

did the trick